# Sequence length encoding using R

Tags: r, encoding

Is there a way to encode *increasing integer sequences* in R, analogous to encoding run lengths using run length encoding (`rle`)?

I'll illustrate with an example:

**Analogy: Run length encoding**

```
r <- c(rep(1, 4), 2, 3, 4, rep(5, 5))
rle(r)
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:5] 4 1 1 1 5
  values : num [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
```

**Desired: sequence length encoding**

```
s <- c(1:4, rep(5, 4), 6:9)
s
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 5 5 5 6 7 8 9

somefunction(s)
Sequence lengths
  lengths: int [1:4] 5 1 1 5
  value1 : num [1:4] 1 5 5 5
```

**Edit 1**

Thus, `somefunction(1:10)` will give the result:

```
Sequence lengths
  lengths: int [1:1] 10
  value1 : num [1:1] 1
```

This results means that there is an integer sequence of length 10 with starting value of 1, i.e. `seq(1, 10)`

Note that there isn't a mistake in my example result.  The vector in fact ends in the sequence 5:9, not 6:9 which was used to construct it.

My use case is that I am working with survey data in an SPSS export file.  Each subquestion in a grid of questions will have a name of the pattern `paste("q", 1:5)`, but sometimes there is an "other" category which will be marked `q_99`, `q_other` or something else.  I wish to find a way of identifying the sequences.

**Edit 2**

In a way, my desired function is the inverse of the base function `sequence`, with the start value, `value1` in my example, added.

```
lengths <- c(5, 1, 1, 5)
value1 <- c(1, 5, 5, 5)

s
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 5 5 5 6 7 8 9
sequence(lengths) + rep(value1-1, lengths) 
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 5 5 5 6 7 8 9
```

**Edit 3**

I should have stated that for my purposes a sequence is defined as **increasing integer sequences** as opposed to monotonically increasing sequences, e.g. `c(4,5,6,7)` but not `c(2,4,6,8)` nor `c(5,4,3,2,1)`.  However, any other integer can appear between sequences.

This means a solution should be able to cope with this test case:

```
somefunction(c(2, 4, 1:4, 5, 5))
    Sequence lengths
      lengths: int [1:4] 1 1 5 1
      value1 : num [1:4] 2 4 1 5
```

In the ideal case, the solution can also cope with the use case suggested originally, which would include characters in the vector, e.g.

```
somefunction(c(2, 4, 1:4, 5, "other"))
    Sequence lengths
      lengths: int [1:5] 1 1 5 1 1
      value1 : num [1:5] 2 4 1 5 "other"
```

Comment: Andrie, I am still not clear how your sequence encoding works. Where do the values come from, and what do the lengths imply? +1 for laying it out with an example, but you can make it more clear.

Comment: Please define: "sequence".  :)  I'm with Ramnath - it's not quite making sense.

Comment: @Ramnath  I hope the edit makes it more clear.  In the sequence 1:10 the lenght is 10, and the value1 is 1.  In other words you can pass these parameters to seq.int to reconcstruct the original vector.  For example `seq.int(1, lenght.out=10)`

Comment: @Iterator.  A sequence is defined the same as the `seq` function in R.  So, 1:5 is the integer sequence from 1 to 5, i.e. `c(1,2,3,4,5)`

Comment: Got it.  So, is this is simply a way of deciding when to switch between `rep` and `seq` in order to reproduce a given vector?  (Where it seems that `rep` has a default replication of 1?)  If so, then that is an interesting encoding question.

Comment: @Iterator Just `seq`, not `rep`. Any repeated values will simply be repeated as elements in the results vector, i.e. `seq.int(..., length.out=1)`

Comment: A suggestion for people answering: a solution that doesn't use `diff`, and uses logical comparisons instead is generalizable (to non-numeric vectors) and could be much faster.

Comment: @Iterator: how would you define a sequence in a non-numerical case?

Comment: @Nick: I have a beautiful definition, but unfortunately the margins of this website are not large enough for me to express it.  :)  Touché, I believe you are correct.

Comment: Can you show us the output of colnames(your_df)? So we can see how the question numbers are labelled? I deal with this frequently with market research data files as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

EDIT : added control to do the character vectors as well.

Based on rle, I come to following solution :

```
somefunction <- function(x){

    if(!is.numeric(x)) x <- as.numeric(x)
    n <- length(x)
    y <- x[-1L] != x[-n] + 1L
    i <- c(which(y|is.na(y)),n)

    list(
      lengths = diff(c(0L,i)),
      values = x[head(c(0L,i)+1L,-1L)]
    )

}

> s <- c(2,4,1:4, rep(5, 4), 6:9,4,4,4)

    > somefunction(s)
    $lengths
    [1] 1 1 5 1 1 5 1 1 1

    $values
    [1] 2 4 1 5 5 5 4 4 4
```

This one works on every test case I tried and uses vectorized values without ifelse clauses. Should run faster. It converts strings to NA, so you keep a numeric output.

```
> S <- c(4,2,1:5,5, "other" , "other",4:6,2)

> somefunction(S)
$lengths
[1] 1 1 5 1 1 1 3 1

$values
[1]  4  2  1  5 NA NA  4  2

Warning message:
In somefunction(S) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Comment: why are 2 and 4 being counted as part of separate subsequences?

Comment: Because @Andrie said that a sequence is defined like in R by using `:`. and 4 does not follow on 2.

Comment: +1 Vectorized - nice!  The way things should be.  It's even called `somefunction`.  Gotta go downvote Andrie for suggesting a bad name. Just kidding.

Answer (score 5):

Here is my solution

```
diff_s = which(diff(s) != 1)
lengths = diff(c(0, diff_s, length(s)))
values  = s[c(1, diff_s + 1)]
```

EDIT: function to take care of strings too

```
sle2 = function(s){
  s2 = as.numeric(s)
  s2[is.na(s2)] = 100 + as.numeric(factor(s[is.na(s2)]))
  diff_s2 = which(diff(s2) != 1)
  lengths = diff(c(0, diff_s2, length(s)))
  values  = s[c(1, diff_s2 + 1)]
  return(list(lengths = lengths, values = values))
}

sle2(c(4,2,1:5,5, "other" , "other",4:6,2, "someother", "someother"))

lengths
 [1] 1 1 5 1 1 1 3 1 1 1

$values
 [1] "4"   "2"  "1"   "5"  "other" "other"  "4"   "2"  "someother" "someother"

Warning message:
In sle2(c(4, 2, 1:5, 5, "other", "other", 4:6, 2, "someother", "someother")) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

Comment: try s <- c(2,4,1:4, rep(5, 4), 6:9,4,4,4) on it. Doesn't work.

Comment: nope. Output should be 1 1 5 1 1 5 1 1 1 for the lengths, but it doesn't give that. ( And please, use `<-` instead of `=` for assignments. I know both work, but still.. )

Comment: nope. here is the sequence (2, 4), (1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (5), (5), (5, 6, 7, 8, 9), (4), (4), (4) with lengths being `2, 5, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1` and starting values `2, 1, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4`

Comment: I think there is a problem that you count on having a lower number after the end of a sequence. As such, your lengths are not correct with (e.g.): `s <- c(2,4,1:4, rep(5, 4), 6:9,12,4,11)`.

Comment: @Nick, Joris. this should fix it as I have a better understanding of subsequence now.

Answer (score 4):

You could use this for a start (given you `s` above):

```
s2<-c(0, diff(s))
s3<-ifelse((c(s2[-1], 0)==1) & (s2!=1), 1, s2)
rle(ifelse(s3==1, -1, seq_along(s3)))
```

It doesn't return the values yet, there are probably easy enough ways to adpat the code. At least you have the sequence lengths, so you can easily retrieve the starting values for the sequences.

Comment: I think that the values may referenced by indices of non-zero elements of `s2` or from the same for a second-pass diff on `s2`.  I'm still getting my head around the original problem of the lengths; the values seem easier to me...

Comment: That's going to cause trouble with c(2,4,1:4,5,5,...)

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
sle <- function(s)
{
    diffs <- which(diff(s)!=1)
    lengths <- c(diffs[1],diff(diffs),length(s)-diffs[length(diffs)])
    value1 <- s[c(1,diffs+1)]
    cat("", "Sequence Length Encoding\n", " lengths:")
    str(lengths)
    cat("  value1:")
    str(value1)
}


sle(s)
 Sequence Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:4] 5 1 1 5
  value1: num [1:4] 1 5 5 5

sle(c(2,4,1:4,rep(5,4),6:9,4,4,4))
 Sequence Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:9] 1 1 5 1 1 5 1 1 1
  value1: num [1:9] 2 4 1 5 5 5 4 4 4
```

Comment: why are 2 and 4 being counted as part of separate sub sequences? the key is how to determine subsequences. my assumption is that the breaking point is when the numbers don't increase. what is yours?

Comment: @Ramnath : as they both form a sequence of length 1?

Comment: @Ramnath I understood that the sequences of interest were consecutive integers.

Comment: This was my original intention, so your solution does what I expected.  @Ramnath, I have edited my question to specify this explicitly.  Now, for an extra challenge, how to cope with characters in the vector?

Comment: @Andrie Don't think it would work with a mixture of numbers and characters, but you could always change the characters to a negative integer to highlight them.

Comment: +1 I think this works.  Rather than changing character to negative integers, perhaps change them to NA, and keep store them as an additional list element.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an enhancement to Joris Meys's solution.  Consider this a solution to a future problem :-) .

Carl

```
seqle <- function(x,incr=1) {
    if(!is.numeric(x)) x <- as.numeric(x)
    n <- length(x)
    #y <- x[-1L] != x[-n] + 1L
    y <- x[-1L] != x[-n] + incr
    i <- c(which(y|is.na(y)),n)
    list( lengths = diff(c(0L,i)),  values = x[head(c(0L,i)+1L,-1L)])
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Ben, for improving the formatting.  I should have done that myself.  BTW, in case people didn't know, this, and Joris' code, are exactly the code in base::rle  with the addition of the "+incr" offset to the formula for y.

Answer (score 0):

"My use case is that I am working with survey data in an SPSS export file. Each subquestion in a grid of questions will have a name of the pattern paste("q", 1:5), but sometimes there is an "other" category which will be marked q_99, q_other or something else. I wish to find a way of identifying the sequences."

I usually do something like this when I'm pulling data from confirmit, DASH, SPSS, SAS, MySQL or whatever depending on the source it always gets punted into a data.frame():

```
surv.pull <- function(dat, pattern) {
  dat <- data.frame(dat[,grep(pattern,colnames(dat))],check.names=F)
return(dat)
}
```

If you use `pattern` like `[q][_][9][9]` you can decide to pull a data.frame of other data spaces by or not by adding "." to the end `[q][_][9][9].` so that it pulls `q_99whatever`

Most of my data columns are in the form like this q8a.1, .3, .4, .5, .6, .7, .8, ... so `surv.pull(dat, "[q][8][a].")` would pull them all, including the other if there was a specify. Obviously, using regex you could decide whether or not to pull the other.

Alternatively, the general convention is to push other specify questions to the end of the data space, so a quick `df <- df[-ncol(df)]` would drop it or `other_list <- df[ncol(df)]` would save it.

Comment: I am familiar with this design pattern, and use it myself.  This is not the issue.  What I want to achieve is to separate the initial sequence from any "other" columns at the end. So, the columns names could be `c("q_1", "q_2", "q_3", "q_99", "q_99_other")`.  My question tries to find a way of separating the initial sequence of 1:3 from the 99. A grep pattern can't easily do that.

Comment: You could always replace 99 with another identifier in the colnames. I usually do that right at the beginning and push them into a verb file for later review. `.[9][9].` (99 is sometimes an other specify column for me). Unless 99 is an actual question number for you? (Omnibus?)

Comment: Yes, but what if it is "q_98" or anything else.  The general pattern is that there is probably a sequence at the start (sometimes an interrupted sequence), and often a motley collection of "other" questions at the end, where "other" is coded differently depending on the panel/omnibus/fieldwork supplier.  I have found that 98 or 99 is often a boolean/numeric indicating that this option was ticked, with "q_99_other" containing the text.

Comment: `names(df[,sapply(df,!is.numeric)])` would give you a listing of all the verbatim columns. So you could probably use that to avoid dealing with the sequencing entirely.