# Sizes of integer vectors in R

Tags: r, memory-management

I had thought that R had a standard overhead for storing objects (24 bytes, it seems, at least for integer vectors), but a simple test revealed that it's more complex than I realized.  For instance, taking integer vectors up to length 100 (using random sampling, hoping to avoid any [sneaky sequence compression tricks that might be out there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077710/sequence-length-encoding-using-r)), I found that different length vectors could have the same size, as follows:

```
> N   = 100
> V   = vector(length = 100)
> for(L in 1:N){
+     z = sample(N, L, replace = TRUE)
+     V[L]    = object.size(z)
+ }
> 
> options('width'=88)
> V
  [1]  48  48  56  56  72  72  72  72  88  88  88  88 104 104 104 104 168 168 168 168
 [21] 168 168 168 168 168 168 168 168 168 168 168 168 176 176 184 184 192 192 200 200
 [41] 208 208 216 216 224 224 232 232 240 240 248 248 256 256 264 264 272 272 280 280
 [61] 288 288 296 296 304 304 312 312 320 320 328 328 336 336 344 344 352 352 360 360
 [81] 368 368 376 376 384 384 392 392 400 400 408 408 416 416 424 424 432 432 440 440
```

I'm very impressed by the `152` values that shows up (observation: 152 = 128 + 24, though 280 = 256 + 24 isn't as prominent).  Can someone explain how these allocations arise?  I have been unable to find a clear definition in the documentation, though V cells come up.

Comment: This could very well be an artifact of the implementation of `object.size`. Note how the help describes it as an estimate...

Comment: @Nick: Oh no, that's kind of spooky, because I depend on `object.size()` a lot. Thanks for the pointer. As I read it uncertainty arises because of possible attribution (or maybe even encoding) issues. But there's not too much simpler in life than integer vectors.

Comment: I agree, though you have to be careful anyways as reuse is often hidden (just look at the object.size of two huge data.frames sharing all but 1 column)

Comment: I updated the table to display as 5x20

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Even if you try N <- 10000, all values occur exactly twice, except for vectors of length :

- 5 to 8 (56 bytes)
- 9 to 12 (72 bytes)
- 13 to 16 (88 bytes)
- 17 to 32 (152 bytes)

The fact that the number of bytes occurs twice, comes from the simple fact that the memory is allocated in pieces of 8 bytes (referred to as Vcells in `?gc` ) and integers take only 4 bytes.

Next to that, the internal structure of objects in R makes a distinguishment between small and large vectors for allocating memory. Small vectors are allocated in bigger blocks of about 2Kb, whereas larger vectors are allocated individually.  The ‘small’ vectors consist of 6 defined classes, based on length, and are able to store vector data of up to 8, 16, 32, 48, 64 and 128 bytes. As an integer takes only 4 bytes, you have 2, 4, 8, 12, 16 and 32 integers you can store in these 6 classes. This explains the pattern you see.

The extra number of bytes is for the header (which forms the Ncells in `?gc`). If you're really interested in all this, read through the [R Internals](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-ints.html) manual.

And, as you guessed, the 24 extra bytes are from the headers (or Ncells ). It's in fact a bit more complicated than that, but the exact details can be found in the [R internals](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-ints.html) manual

Comment: +1 for a very insightful answer, and +1 (if I could) for using "distinguishment".

Comment: aargh... that should be "distinguishes" instead of "makes a distinguishment". It's Dutch translated to english.

Comment: No, it's fine: distinguishment is a synonym for distinction.  It's just not commonly used by mere mortals.