# Why is an R object so much larger than the same data in Stata/SPSS?

Tags: r, memory, survey

I have survey data in `SPSS` and `Stata` which is `~730 MB` in size. Each of these programs also occupy approximately the amount of space you would expect(`~800MB`) in the memory if I'm working with that data.

I've been trying to pick up `R`, and so attempted to load this data into `R`. No matter what method I try(`read.dta` from the `stata` file, `fread` from a `csv` file, `read.spss` from the `spss` file) the `R` object(measured using `object.size()`) is between `2.6 to 3.1 GB` in size. If I save the object in an `R` file, that is less than `100 MB`, but on loading it is the same size as before.

Any attempts to analyse the data using the survey package, particularly if I try and `subset` the data, take significantly longer than the equivalent command in `stata`.

e.g I have a household size variable `'hhpers'` in my data `'hh'`, weighted by variable `'hhwt'` , subset by `'htype'`

R code :

```
require(survey)
sv.design <- svydesign(ids =  ~0,data = hh, weights = hh$hhwt)
rm(hh)
system.time(svymean(~hhpers,sv.design[which
(sv.design$variables$htype=="rural"),]))
```

pushes the memory used by R upto 6 GB and takes a very long time  - 
 user  system elapsed 
   `3.70    1.75  144.11`

The equivalent operation in stata

```
svy: mean hhpers if htype == 1
```

completes almost instantaneously, giving me the same result.

Why is there such a massive difference between both memory usage(by object as well as the function), and time taken between `R` and `Stata`? 
Is there anything I can do to optimise the data and how `R` is working with it?

ETA:  My machine is running 64 bit Windows 8.1, and I'm running R with no other programs loaded. At the very least, the environment is no different for R than it is for Stata.

After some digging, I expect the reason for this is R's limited number of data types. All my data is stored as int, which takes 4 bytes per element. In survey data, each response is categorically coded, and typically requires only one byte to store, which stata stores using the 'byte' data type, and R stores using the 'int' data type, leading to some significant inefficiency in large surveys.

Comment: Did you try to `set virtual` in Stata to on? Can you compare the object sizes after doing that?

Comment: What is the result of `str(hh)`? Could this be related to factors?

Comment: There are 917 variables in the dataset, so str(hh) doesn't really offer up anything immediately useful. Most variables seem to be int though.

Comment: set virtual does not have any effect in stata

Comment: try using `library(haven)` and `read_spss()` instead of `library(foreign)` and `read.spss()`

Comment: The description of your setup is not sufficiently complete. Guessing Windows of some flavor. We can try 20 questions, of course. What other programs do you have loaded at the time you start R? Have you tried starting your OS and R with no other programs loaded. You need to clarify sizes of file in RAM versus file. Use appropriate functions and show full output. `?"Memory-limits"`. Anthony would be the best person to opine about the claim of "equivalence" of hte code.

Comment: @BondedDust My machine is running 64 bit Windows 8.1, and I'm running R with no other programs loaded. At the very least, the environment is no different for R than it is for Stata. I have clarified sizes of file in RAM vs. file in my original question. It is a 730 MB file in Stata, and the Stata program occupies approximately 850 MB RAM according to task manager.  In R, the object size using the 'object.size()' function is `2717423200 bytes' and the RAM occupied y the R session is 2251.9 MB. Are there any other details I can provide?

Comment: @BondedDust Also please note that I'm not claiming that the code is equivalent across the two softwares. I am only saying that the equivalent operation, that gets me the same result in stata takes far less time. I have explicitly asked how I can optimise the way R is working with the data, which to me certainly includes any changes in the code that would bring improvements.

Comment: @AnthonyDamico  'library(haven)' and 'read_spss()' actually result in an even larger object

Comment: Hm, looks like you need a package to get anything smaller than integer type. (Apparently, even booleans are not as small as they could be: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9178254/why-do-logicals-booleans-in-r-require-4-bytes).

Comment: @Frank Yes, I also came across the 'ff' package that implements some functionality which would give access to smaller data types, but using these packages seems to significantly complicate analysis, and I'm not sure if you could even use it to perform analysis using other packages without translating data back and forth between standard R data types.

Comment: If the survey is publicly available (which in many cases are), you should provide the link so that other can test it and you will have answers instantly.

Comment: @bldysabba http://asdfree.com/ hosts r code to work with many public use survey data sets.  the ones too big to fit in ram on 4GB machines are easily stored in database-backed survey objects.  i'm not intending to answer your question here, only mentioning this because the data size loaded in ram doesn't really matter for survey analysis with r.  specific examples:  https://github.com/ajdamico/usgsd/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=RSQLite+OR+MonetDB.R&type=Code

Answer (score 1):

Regarding difference in memory usage - you're on the right track and (mostly) its because of object types. Indeed integer saving will take up a lot of your memory. So proper setting of variable types would improve memory usage by R. `as.factor()` would help. See `?as.factor` for more details to update this *after* reading data. To fix this *during* reading data from the file refer to `colClasses` parameter of `read.table()` (and similar functions specific for stata & SPSS formats). This will help R store data more efficiently (its on the fly guessing of types is not top-notch).

Regarding the second part - calculation speed - large dataset parsing is not perfect in base R, that's where `data.table` package comes handy - its fast and quite similar to original `data.frame` behavior.  Summary calcuations are really quick. You would use it via `hh <- as.data.table(read.table(...))` and you can calculate something similar to your example with

```
hh <- as.data.table(hh)
hh[htype == "rural",mean(hhpers*hhwt)]
## or
hh[,mean(hhpers*hhwt),by=hhtype] # note 'empty' first argument
```

Sorry, I'm not familiar with survey data studies, so I can't be more specific.

Another detail into memory usage by function - most likely R made a copy of your entire dataset to calculate the summaries you were looking for. Again, in this case `data.table` would help and prevent R from making excessive copies and improve memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

Of interest may also be the `memisc` package which, for me, resulted in much smaller eventual files than `read.spss` (I was however working at a smaller scale than you)

From the `memisc` vignette

> ... Thus this package provides facilities to load such subsets of variables, without the need to load a complete data set. Further, the loading of data from SPSS files is organized in such a way that all informations about variable labels, value labels, and user-defined missing values are retained. This is made possible by the definition of importer objects, for which a subset method exists. importer objects contain only the information about the variables in the external data set but not the data. The data itself is loaded into memory when the functions subset or as.data.set are used.