# Collapse continuous integer runs to strings of ranges

Tags: r, design-patterns, range

I have some data in a list that I need to look for continuous runs of integers (My brain think`rle` but don't know how to use it here).

It's easier to look at the data set and explain what I'm after.

**Here's the data view:**

```
$greg
 [1]  7  8  9 10 11 20 21 22 23 24 30 31 32 33 49

$researcher
[1] 42 43 44 45 46 47 48

$sally
 [1] 25 26 27 28 29 37 38 39 40 41

$sam
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6 16 17 18 19 34 35 36

$teacher
[1] 12 13 14 15
```

**Desired output:**

```
$greg
 [1]  7:11, 20:24, 30:33, 49

$researcher
 [1] 42:48

$sally
 [1] 25:29, 37:41

$sam
 [1]  1:6, 16:19 34:36

$teacher
 [1] 12:15
```

Use base packages how can I replace continuous span with a colon between highest and lowest and commas in between non the non continuous parts? Note that the data goes from a list of integer vectors to a list of character vectors.

**MWE data:**

```
z <- structure(list(greg = c(7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
    23L, 24L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 49L), researcher = 42:48, sally = c(25L, 
    26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L), sam = c(1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 34L, 35L, 36L), teacher = 12:15), .Names = c("greg", 
    "researcher", "sally", "sam", "teacher"))
```

Comment: Your question is a bit similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7077710/602276

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think `diff` is the solution. You might need some additional fiddling to deal with the singletons, but:

```
lapply(z, function(x) {
  diffs <- c(1, diff(x))
  start_indexes <- c(1, which(diffs > 1))
  end_indexes <- c(start_indexes - 1, length(x))
  coloned <- paste(x[start_indexes], x[end_indexes], sep=":")
  paste0(coloned, collapse=", ")
})

$greg
[1] "7:11, 20:24, 30:33, 49:49"

$researcher
[1] "42:48"

$sally
[1] "25:29, 37:41"

$sam
[1] "1:6, 16:19, 34:36"

$teacher
[1] "12:15"
```

Comment: This one I liked the most because I could understand everything you did.  I made one small tweak to get `49:49` as `49` but that was the easy part.  Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Using [`IRanges`](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/IRanges.html):

```
require(IRanges)
lapply(z, function(x) {
    t <- as.data.frame(reduce(IRanges(x,x)))[,1:2]
    apply(t, 1, function(x) paste(unique(x), collapse=":"))
})

# $greg
# [1] "7:11"  "20:24" "30:33" "49"   
# 
# $researcher
# [1] "42:48"
# 
# $sally
# [1] "25:29" "37:41"
# 
# $sam
# [1] "1:6"   "16:19" "34:36"
# 
# $teacher
# [1] "12:15"
```

Comment: Works very well.  Not in base but useful for future searchers.  Thank you. +1

Comment: Sure, anything related to intervals, it is better to use package that implements `interval trees`.

Comment: Yeah this was the first time I've seen `IRanges`

Answer (score 6):

Here is an attempt using `diff` and `tapply` returning a character vector

```
runs <- lapply(z, function(x) {
  z <- which(diff(x)!=1); 
  results <- x[sort(unique(c(1,length(x), z,z+1)))]
  lr <- length(results)
  collapse <- rep(seq_len(ceiling(lr/2)),each = 2, length.out = lr)
  as.vector(tapply(results, collapse, paste, collapse = ':'))
  })

runs
$greg
[1] "7:11"  "20:24" "30:33" "49"   

$researcher
[1] "42:48"

$sally
[1] "25:29" "37:41"

$sam
[1] "1:6"   "16:19" "34:36"

$teacher
[1] "12:15"
```

Comment: When I think I'm getting good at R I look at code like this and realize I have a lot to learn +1

Comment: I'm not quite sure that is a compliment :).

Comment: No it is. There were some combinations of functions I wouldn't have thought to put together :-)  I liked the creativity.

Answer (score 5):

I have a fairly similar solution to Marius, his works as well as  mine but the mechanisms are slightly different so I thought I may as well post it:

```
findIntRuns <- function(run){
  rundiff <- c(1, diff(run))
  difflist <- split(run, cumsum(rundiff!=1))
  unname(sapply(difflist, function(x){
    if(length(x) == 1) as.character(x) else paste0(x[1], ":", x[length(x)])
  }))
}

lapply(z, findIntRuns)
```

Which produces:

```
$greg
[1] "7:11"  "20:24" "30:33" "49"   

$researcher
[1] "42:48"

$sally
[1] "25:29" "37:41"

$sam
[1] "1:6"   "16:19" "34:36"

$teacher
[1] "12:15"
```

Answer (score 5):

Another short solution with `lapply` and `tapply`:

```
lapply(z, function(x)
  unname(tapply(x, c(0, cumsum(diff(x) != 1)), FUN = function(y) 
    paste(unique(range(y)), collapse = ":")
  ))
)
```

The result:

```
$greg
[1] "7:11"  "20:24" "30:33" "49"   

$researcher
[1] "42:48"

$sally
[1] "25:29" "37:41"

$sam
[1] "1:6"   "16:19" "34:36"

$teacher
[1] "12:15"
```

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party, but here's a `deparse` based one-liner:

```
lapply(z,function(x) paste(sapply(split(x,cumsum(c(1,diff(x)-1))),deparse),collapse=", "))
$greg
[1] "7:11, 20:24, 30:33, 49L"

$researcher
[1] "42:48"

$sally
[1] "25:29, 37:41"

$sam
[1] "1:6, 16:19, 34:36"

$teacher
[1] "12:15"
```

Comment: Nice approach +1 definitely late to the party ;)