# Casting ordered data

Tags: r

I've managed to get data in the format:

```
run    type1
data1  12
data2  13
run    type2
data1  14
data2  15
...
```

I want:

```
run    data1 data2
type1     12    13
type2     14    15
...
```

I've tried cast/dcast to no avail.  Any suggestions?

sample data:

```
data.frame(matrix(c("run","type1","data1",12,"data2",13,"run","type2","data1",14,"data3",15), ncol=2, byrow=T))
```

Comment: How and why did you get the data in that format?

Comment: That's how it was given to me.

Comment: I assumed that "I've managed to get..." meant this was the output of your actions. Sorry :-)

Comment: Is it supposed to be `data3` there? Because in your example there was no `data3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my suggestion:

```
cast.runs <- function(d) {
  isrun <- d[[1]]=="run"
  whichrun <- which(isrun)
  lens <- diff(c(whichrun, nrow(d)+1))
  runlabels <- inverse.rle(list(lengths=lens, values=d[[2]][whichrun]))
  return(cbind(run=runlabels, d)[!isrun,])
}
```

This function will yield suitable long format, which you can then recast as you see fit:

```
  runlabels    X1 X2
2     type1 data1 12
3     type1 data2 13
5     type2 data1 14
6     type2 data3 15
```

Unsurprisingly, I start by identifying the `run` lines. I cound how many rows there are for each run, including the title row. That code is inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7078398/1468366). Next I repeat each run label that many times, and in the end I drop the title rows.

One possible way to cast this output would be using the `dcast` function from the `reshape2` package:

```
> dcast(cast.runs(d), run ~ X1)
Using X2 as value column: use value.var to override.
    run data1 data2 data3
1 type1    12    13  <NA>
2 type2    14  <NA>    15
```

Comment: Accepted for generalized function.

Comment: @DavidArenburg: Now it does…